# Сохранение объектов из Kafka consumer в Postgesql

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, pojo, apache-kafka

Есть Java приложение с Kafka consumer, которое принимает объекты из топиков.
Также используется схема Avro.

Как можно полученные объекты из топика записать в Postgres?

POJO-классы с JPA аннотациями написать не могу, так как структура объектов может меняться.
Могу сгенерировать классы объектов из avro схемы, но они генерируются без JPA  аннотаций.

Какие есть варианты решения?
Заранее благодарен за помощь.

P.S: еще есть SQL схема для создания таблиц, может из нее как-то можно сгенерить нужные классы с аннотациями?

Comment: Если вы хотите записывать в `Postgre` полученные данные, то вам надо сделать под них структуру таблиц. А если вы не знаете заранее стурктуры данных - то вариант писать их как ключ-значение. В качестве значения сделать в `Postgre` поле типа `json` и преобразовывать  полученные из `Kafka` объекты в Json(если там классы, к примеру)

Comment: Не совсем понял. У меня есть sql схема таблиц, из нее созданы таблицы в Postgres. Далее из kafka приходят объекты для записи в эти таблицы. Поля в таблице и поля объектов принятых из кафки соответствуют.

Comment: А почему вы тогда не можете сделать `DAO` и `Entity` классы для `Postgres`, принять данные от `Kafka`, сконвертировать в `Entity` и записать? Менятся может структура объектов, поступающих от `kafka`?

Comment: Да, так и есть, иногда меняется структура объектов. По этой причине не могу прописать POJO вручную.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем готовых решений не нашел.
Через JSONParser парсил данные из топика и запиживал в базу через JDBC